# Android Google DRIVE API V3 - query folders does not return all folders

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

Currently my team is working on both iOS and Android system.
We have 2 individual Apps, and our idea is - using Google Drive as a data relay.
That is, our Android App packs a zip file, uploads it to Google Drive, 
and then the iOS App downloads it for further processing.

Our team is sharing a Google account, so the data is uploaded to and downloaded from the same Google account.

I followed the tutorials of how to sign-in with Google Account:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

And I've also linked up my App in the Google API Console.
(By establishing credentials using the SHA5 key of my App.)
My App is now capable of uploading files to and create folders on Google Drive using Drive API.
However, when I want to list all folders on the Google Drive, 
I found out that my Android App can **ONLY** see the folders it created.
I changed the query condition to files, and it also can ONLY return the files it has uploaded.

I asked my colleague who implements the iOS App and uses the iOS version of Drive API.
He says that his iOS App can see **ALL** the folders and files on the Google Drive storage.
And both of our Apps are still in debug stage (not in App store, or release mode).

Am I missing something? Or is this some kind of privacy protection mechanism?

Here's my query code in Java:

```
    void queryAllFolders() {
        if(isReady()) {
            Task<FileList> queryAllFoldersTask = queryAllGoogleDriveFolders();
            if(queryAllFoldersTask != null) {
                queryAllFoldersTask.addOnCompleteListener(this::onQueryAllFoldersCompleted);
                queryAllFoldersTask.addOnFailureListener(this::onQueryAllFoldersFailed);
            }
        }
    }

    private Task<FileList> queryAllGoogleDriveFolders() {
        try{
            return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
                // Retrieve the metadata as a FileList object.
                String pageToken = null;
                FileList result;
                do {
                    mLogger.debug("[queryAllGoogleDriveFolders] start query");
                    result = mDriveService.files().list()
                            .setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false")
                            .setSpaces("drive")
                            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                            .setPageToken(pageToken)
                            .execute();
                    for (File file : result.getFiles()) {
                        mLogger.debug("[queryAllGoogleDriveFolders] Found folder: " + file.getName() + " with ID: " + file.getId());
                    }
                    pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
                } while (pageToken != null);

                return result;
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLogger.error("[queryAllGoogleDriveFolders] Error querying Google Drive folders: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(onQueryAllFoldersFailedCallback != null) { onQueryAllFoldersFailedCallback.run(); }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The "trashed=false" does not affect the result of query - other folders that are not created by my Android App is still unseen whether this condition is added.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because iOS apply internal debug mode, so he can use `.../auth/drive` scope, but default you only have `.../auth/drive.file` scope, it only allow you to access the content created by your app.
You can refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive) for the details